# silverlight Canvas and Rectangle mouse events

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mouseevent

I have the following controls in xaml:

```
<Canvas Height="500" Width="500" Name="canPreview" VerticalAlignment="top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" MouseLeftButtonDown="canPreview_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                MouseLeftButtonUp="canPreview_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeave="canPreview_MouseLeave" MouseMove="canPreview_MouseMove"
                Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=imgPreview}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=imgPreview}">
            <Rectangle Name="recSelection" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" Fill="Transparent"  Opacity=".5" Height="100" Width="100" />
        </Canvas>
```

And for some reason the Canvas events only fire when the mouse pointer is above the rectangle.  Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background color of the Canvas; you can't click something that isn't drawn.

You can use the Transparent brush if you do not want to see the canvas, it will be clickable.